# closest number before a given number in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am facing issue in getting a last recent number from a given number (this given number is coming from a different table)

The requirement is:

```
Table A

Person Person_Entry_No

1       100

1       200

1       400
```

```
Table B

Person Person_Test

1       300
```

I need the output as

The most recent entry number(before) when a person is gone for test (person_test)

```
Person  Person_entry_no

1       200
```

I tried using `LIMIT 1` to get only one record from table 1 ... but it is not working.

Comment: _"I tried using LIMIT 1 to get only one record from table 1"_ Could you provide the actual query ? I assume there are many things to explain here...

Comment: ... like for example, the `LIMIT` clause being a MySQL extension, not available in Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

`limit` isn't supported by Oracle Enterprise Database. Instead, you can use the `fetch first` clause:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   a
JOIN   b ON a.person = b.person AND a.person_entry_no  < b.person_test
ORDER BY a.person_entry_no DESC  
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: Where does your query say it should get the closest value below `person_test`. This will just pick any row below it, not the closest one.

Comment: @Barmar completely missed the `order by` clause for some reason... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b ON ( b.Person = a.Person AND a.Person_Entry_No <= b.PersonTest )
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'b'
                 FROM TableA a2
                 WHERE a2.Person = a.Person
                 AND a2.Person_Entry_No <= b.PersonTest
                 AND a2.Person_Entry_No > a.Person_Entry_No    
               )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a dependent subquery with MAX:

```
SELECT b.*,
       (  SELECT max(Person_Entry_No) 
         FROM tableA a
         WHERE a.Person = b.Person
           AND a.Person_Entry_No < b.Person_Test
       ) As the_most_recen_entry_number
FROM tableB b
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d53e2/1

Answer (score 1):

Use `MAX()` to get the highest value.

```
SELECT A.Person, MAX(A.Person_Entry_No)
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.Person = B.Person AND A.Person_Entry_No < B.Person_Test
GROUP BY A.Person
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this for more than just one person you should go for a Windowed Aggregate Function:

```
select *
from 
 (
   SELECT a.*, b.Person_Test,
      row_number() -- rank the entry numbers
      over (partition by b.Person
            order by a.Person_Entry_No desc) as rn
   FROM TableA a
   JOIN TableB b ON a.Person = b.Person 
   where a.person_entry_no  < b.Person_Test
 ) dt
 where rn = 1 -- only the first row
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d53e2/9)